# Pandas convert column with strings comma separated to binary

Tags: pandas, string, binary

in Pandas I have an excel file (called Data) with 12 columns, in the 7th column (called Operations) I have many strings for each line (some repeated) separated by comma and space but there's some string separated only by space that I want to leave together (stringA, my string,B my stringC, ecc.)

[image]

and I need to create a list, or something similar, and convert each unique string to binary like eg

[image]

How can i do it? I've tried so many code but none work. thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use images, your initial format was better!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html).

If the separator is always `<comma><space>`:

```
out = df.join(df['Column 7th'].str.get_dummies(sep=r', '))
```

Else, combine it with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
out = df.join(df['Column 7th']
              .str.replace(r',\s*', '|', regex=True)
              .str.get_dummies())
```

Output:

```
                     Column 7th  my string2  my string5  string1  string3  string4  string6
0  string1, my string2, string3           1           0        1        1        0        0
1  string4, my string5, string1           0           1        1        0        1        0
2  string6, string1, my string5           0           1        1        0        0        1
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! when i run the code i get this error:  columns overlap but no suffix specified. how can i fix it? I could also add the binary conversion columns after all other columns

Comment: Do you already have columns other than "Column 7th" in `df`? Try to add `rsuffix='_right'` as parameter to `join` (e.g. `df.join(df['Column 7th'].str.get_dummies(sep=r', '), rsuffix='_right')`)

Comment: I have a lot of column, I've tried your code but the error is the same. I've tried this: out = out.join(out['7th column'].str.get_dummies(sep=r', '), rsuffix='_right')
out = out.join(out['7th column']
              .str.replace(r',\s*', '|', regex=True)
              .str.get_dummies())

Comment: @plambertini can you provide a (minimal) reproducible input? `df.to_dict()` helps generating a reproducible format

Comment: the result it's too long (my excel file has a lot of column)

Comment: then a **minimal** example that reproduces the issue

Comment: {'Column 1': {0: 'PR-0001',
  1: 'PR-0002',
  2: 'PR-0003',
  3: 'PR-0004',
  4: 'PR-0005',
  111: 'PR-0125',
  112: 'PR-0127',
  113: 'PR-0128',
  114: 'PR-0130',
  115: 'PR-0131'},
…….
…….
'Column 7': {0: 'Duodenite erosiva',
  1: 'NO_COMORBIDITA',
  2: 'DISLIPIDEMIA',
  3: 'NO_COMORBIDITA',
  ...
  114: 'OSAS, CARDIOPATIA ISCHIMICA, IPA',
  115: 'DISLIPEDEMIA, IPA'},

and others 91 columns.
I hope it is clear

Comment: in the 7th column i have the strings that i have to convert but i need to insert the new created column after the 7th column and before the others columns that are already present

Comment: thank yooouuuuu. i've resolved with your suggestion!! thank you. Now I have to made the same thing with the 8th column because i have the same error ( columns overlap but no suffix specified). do you have any advice for me?

Comment: hi @mozway! compared to my first post, your solution works perfectly for the 7th column. now my problem is that I have to do the same thing also for the eighth column, which is as content, equal to the seventh. if I try to use the string you recommended for both the seventh and eighth columns I get the error "columns overlap but no suffix specified" and I can't figure out why. can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

What I would is, first convert that column to list. You can create function with appy or using iterrow.

```
my_list = my_string.split(",")
```

Once it is as a list, you can apply this.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)

df = df.join(
            pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(
                mlb.fit_transform(df.pop('Column7th')),
                index=df.index,
                columns=mlb.classes_))
```

Another option is would be to do this, but it is probably slower.

```
df.drop('Column7th', 1).join(df.Column7th.str.join('|').str.get_dummies())
```